# iPython shell - how to use $EDITOR to edit commands

Tags: ipython, editor

In a terminal emulator with readline support, I can use key binding `Ctrl-X Ctrl-E` to bring up `$EDITOR` to edit a command.

How do I do that in iPython to bring up `$EDITOR` to edit *half-finished* code?

P.S. My $EDITOR is set to "vim -u ".

Answer (score 1):

shortcuts used:
'g' to launch gvim with the content of current cell (you can replace gvim with whatever text editor you like).
so, when you want to edit the cell with your preferred editor, hit 'g', make the changes you want to the cell, save the file in your editor (and then quit), then press 'u'.